# This recursive call could get stuck in an infinit loop. How do i jump out of it?

Tags: php, recursion, infinite-loop

So im accessing some data via an oAuth2 access token and i want to catch the expiration of the access token. When it expires i catch the error code and refresh the token. After that i call the function recursivly. 
If the refresh token for some reason does not work, it would loop infinitly.
How do i jump out of this loop after 1 try?

```php
function companyList($page){
//send http-request
    if($obj['errors']['status'] == '401'){
        Authentication::refreshToken();
        companyList($page);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a global counter that increases 1 step each time it refresh the token and add a if clause that compares it to the refresh limit you wish.

Example:

```
$counter = 0;
function companyList($page){
    global $counter;
    //send http-request
    if($obj['errors']['status'] == '401' && $counter < 5){
        Authentication::refreshToken();
        $counter++;
        companyList($page);
    } elseif($counter >= 5){
        $counter = 0;
    }
}
```

Hope this helps you!

Comment: This is helpfull, but this function will be called a lot which means, that if the token expired 5 times the function will not try to refresh the token anymore.

Comment: Oh, yes. My fault. One more code line hahaha
I'll update my answer.

Now when the counter reachs 5 it just resets itself and stills ends the infinite loop.

Comment: that fixed it now! thank you :)